# filesystem disk space usage not being updated - RHEL5, LVM, ext3

Tags: centos, lvm

On a RHEL5 system, running LVM 2.02/17, my ext3 filesystem does not update the stats in "df -h".  I've almost used up the filesystem's freespace with files I manually created with both dd and copying log files from /var.  Yet df still says the filesystem is 40% free.

The system has been running for most of a year, but I am not allowed to reboot or unmount/remount.

Any advice is appreciated....Lyle

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  In spite of trying 2 different ways to create large files for testing, "du" showed they were allocated, but not really large.

Please ignore the question....Lyle